# How to convert multiple Spark dataframes into a Dataset[Map[String, Array]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to take a Map[String, DataFrame] and convert it to a Dataset[Map[String, Array]]

```scala
val map_of_df = Map(
 "df1"->sc.parallelize(1 to 4).map(i => (i,i*1000)).toDF("id","x").repartition(4)
,"df2"->sc.parallelize(1 to 4).map(i => (i,i*100)).toDF("id","y").repartition(4)
)

//map_of_df: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = Map(df1 -> [id: int, x: int], df2 -> [id: int, y: int])

//magic here, I need a type of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Map[String, Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]] with four partitions
//where the keys to the map are "df1" and "df2"
```

Comment: I don't think thats feasible, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to do some operations on (for example) partition 1 of both df1 and df2 inside a single mapPartitions function in Scala-space.

Comment: I *think* it's possible with careful partitioning, pulling the parquet filenames into driver memory as described by @shay__, and the loading the file fragments in a mapPartitions using direct file reading from hdfs.  However that feels pretty brittle to me.  I was hoping one of the Scala gods would have something a little more elegant

Answer (score 0):

You simply `collect` all DataFrames:

```
map_of_df
      .mapValues(_.collect())
      .toSeq
      .toDS
```

Keep in mind that this will not scale - all data will be loaded into the driver memory. In other words, you don't need Spark for this.

Comment: this does not give the required type

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  The reason I'm using Spark is because the data is large.  The scalability is a requirement for this particular question.